# Get the exact command error output displayed in console into a Powershell variable

Tags: powershell, console, output

I'm writing some scripts to backup registry and I encountered 2 small issues. The 1st one is that I can't intercept the error output of the `reg export` command.

Example:

`reg export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\OpenVPN-GUI test.reg`

Writes this to console because the key is not available:

`ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.`

I would love to get this **exact** string.

Assigning the command to a variable results in an empty string, even with `Out-String`:

`$regerror = reg export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\OpenVPN-GUI test.reg | Out-String`

The closest solution I've found is this kind of redirection:

`$regerror = & reg export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\OpenVPN-GUI test.reg 2>&1`

But that displays:

```
reg.exe : ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
At line:1 char:9
+ $test = & reg export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\OpenVPN-GUI test.reg  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: The syst...y key or value.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to get the mentioned exact output without attempting to process the text above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply convert the stderr lines to *strings*:

```
$regerror = 
  reg export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\OpenVPN-GUI test.reg 2>&1 | 
    ForEach-Object ToString
```

While stderr are are strings to begin with, PowerShell wraps them in [`[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances when you use a `2>` redirection, which is what causes them to render like PowerShell errors when printed to the display.
(In PowerShell (Core) 7+, they no longer *render* as such, but they're still wrapped in `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances).

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was missing!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Destroy666; my pleasure.